# Is it possible to add an additional option to a collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have something like this (HAML):

```
 =form_for @users do |u|
   %p=u.label :name
   %p=u.text_field :name
   %p=u.label :surname
   %p=u.text_field :surname
   %strong='Section'
   =u.collection_select(:section_id, Section.all, :id, :name)
```

How do I add an additional option to the collection_select that's not just an empty value? If I use ":prompt => 'Please select an option'" this will simply add the prompt at the top of the select, but what if I want to add something like "None" with the value of "5"? Like this:

```
 <option value="5">None</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
```

I have the impression this is incredibly simple and I do not see it.

Comment: You can achieve it by having code in helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your special option is a section with id of 5 and name "None". That means you can prepend it to the array of all sections from database. You should probably do that in a controller action:

```
@sections = []
@sections << Section.new(id: 5, name: "None")
@sections += Section.all
```

Then use it in your view.

```
= u.collection_select(:section_id, @sections, :id, :name)
```

Comment: That did it. I knew it was simple. Last thing, is it possible to keep it as an ActiveRecord instead of a hash variable?

Comment: You mean keep the ActiveRecord relation so that you can apply SQL like `@sections.where(foo: "bar").order(:name)`? That's not possible. You have to apply this at the last step when you have the final sections list. It doesn't have to be in the controller, could be done in a helper method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by having custom helper method like:

```
def custom_section_collection_select
  section_options = []
  Section.each do |sec|
    section_options << content_tag(:option, "#{sec.name}", value: sec.id)
  end
  section_options << content_tag(:option, "None", value: "5")
  section_options # return value
end
```

Then in view call:

```
= u.custom_section_collection_select
```

**Note**
It is recommended not to use hardcoded value (like 5 or anything), as if you create section which could have same id.

***Update***

```
def custom_collection_select(model, text, val, with_default)
  options = []
  model.to_s.classify.constantize.each do |rec|
    options << content_tag(:option, "#{rec.send(text)}", value: rec.send(val))
  end
  options << content_tag(:option, "None", value: "5") if with_default
  options # return value
end
```

Then in view:

```
= u.custom_collection_select("section", :name, :id, true)
```

Comment: The value of 5 was just an example. It's a variable value that comes from the database, but this was the simplest way to explain it.

Comment: Cool... The example I provided will only work for `Section` but you can easily make it more generic.

Comment: Interesting. I already marked the other suggestion as the correct answer, but I'll take a look at yours. Perhaps I can apply it to something else. And yes, I'd likely make it more generic. In my example, the select list would usually have 10 or so options, but I wanted to include one option that would be necessary every now and then, that's not necessarily in the same table. If it was hardcoded or not, wasn't really much of an issue cause that value wouldn't change much (if at all).